# Pulumi with GitHub Actions crashing parallel workflows with error: [409] Conflict: Another update is currently in progress. (e.g. with renovate)

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, pulumi

Using GitHub Actions with Pulumi is a great experience because of [the good Actions provided](https://github.com/pulumi/actions). But I tend to run into problems, where multiple GitHub Action workflows run in parallel (e.g. when [renovate](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate) is configured and tries to update the repositories dependencies). So either the first workflow wins and does it's job - and the others fail. Or every workflow fails (which also depends on the GitHub Action workflow design). Then I get errors like this (see [the full log here](https://github.com/jonashackt/azure-training-pulumi/runs/1977168868?check_suite_focus=true)):

```
#### :tropical_drink: `pulumi --non-interactive up`
Previewing update (dev)

View Live: https://app.pulumi.com/jonashackt/scmbreakoutpulumi/dev/previews/fbf45825-5d8f-45bc-ad3e-c55b7576313e


    pulumi:pulumi:Stack scmbreakoutpulumi-dev running 
    azure:core:ResourceGroup scm-breakout-rg-pulumi  
    azure:storage:Account scmbreakresources  
    azure:appservice:Plan asp-scmbreakoutrg  
    azure:storage:Container rawimages  
    azure:storage:Queue thumbnails  
    azure:storage:Container thumbnails  
 +  azure:appservice:AppService scmContactsApi create 
 +  azure:appservice:AppService scmResourceApi create 
 +  azure:appservice:FunctionApp scmFunctionApp create 
 +  azure:appservice:Slot scmResourceApiStg create 
    pulumi:pulumi:Stack scmbreakoutpulumi-dev  
 
Resources:
    + 4 to create
    7 unchanged

Updating (dev)

error: [409] Conflict: Another update is currently in progress.
To learn more about possible reasons and resolution, visit https://www.pulumi.com/docs/troubleshooting/#conflict
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log already leads to a good resource: https://www.pulumi.com/docs/troubleshooting/#conflict It's actually a feature of the Pulumi state management provided by app.pulumi.com:

> One of the services that pulumi.com provides is concurrency control.
> The service will allow at most one user to update a particular stack
> at a time.

So using only one Stack like the default `dev` at app.pulumi.com it looks like this:

[image]

Using GitHub Actions or other CI/CD platforms, this becomes an obstacle. I see 2 options here: We could either switch to another Pulumi state management backend (like [the Local Filesystem Backend](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/state/#logging-into-the-local-filesystem-backend), which would not create a stack on app.pulumi.com but rather CI locally). Or we could create a GitHub Action job specific stack on app.pulumi.com, where the stack is named after the specific job id or something.

As I don't mind to use app.pulumi.com here - and also use the additional log, if something did go wrong - I wanted to have a solution for the second option. The GitHub Action workflow file design could be described with the following steps:

1. Standard Pulumi GitHub Action pipeline: Defining needed variables, checking out the repo, setting up the nodejs environment incl. installing the npm dependencies - and finally configuring the Pulumi CLI using the [action-install-pulumi-cli](https://github.com/pulumi/action-install-pulumi-cli) Action.
2. Creating a Pulumi stack on app.pulumi.com using `pulumi stack init github-${{ github.run_id }}`, which resembles [the `github.run_id` GitHub Action default context variable](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#github-context). This variables represents "a unique number for each run within a repository."
3. Leveraging the (or multiple) [pulumi/actions@v2](https://github.com/pulumi/actions) Action in version `v2` (since only [from v2 we have the `stack-name` configuration option](https://github.com/pulumi/actions#configuration)) and configuring the Pulumi app.pulumi.com stack name with `stack-name: github-${{ github.run_id }}`
4. Removing the Pulumi app.pulumi.com stack using a final `pulumi stack rm github-${{ github.run_id }} -y`

The full GitHub Action workflow looks like this:

```
name: pulumi-preview-up

on: [push]

env:
  ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
  ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_ID }}
  ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ARM_CLIENT_SECRET }}
  ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.ARM_TENANT_ID }}
  PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PULUMI_ACCESS_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  preview-up-destroy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: In order to use the Pulumi v2 action, we need to setup the Pulumi project specific language environment
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'

      - name: After setting up the Pulumi project specific language environment, we need to install the dependencies also (see https://github.com/pulumi/actions#example-workflows)
        run: npm install

      - name: Install Pulumi CLI so that we can create a GHA pipeline specific Pulumi Stack
        uses: pulumi/action-install-pulumi-cli@v1.0.1

      - name: Create GHA pipeline specific Pulumi Stack incl. Azure location
        run: |
          pulumi stack init github-${{ github.run_id }}
          pulumi config set azure:location WestEurope

      - uses: pulumi/actions@v2
        with:
          command: preview
          stack-name: github-${{ github.run_id }}

      - uses: pulumi/actions@v2
        with:
          command: up
          stack-name: github-${{ github.run_id }}

      - uses: pulumi/actions@v2
        with:
          command: destroy
          stack-name: github-${{ github.run_id }}

      - name: Remove the GHA pipeline specific Pulumi Stack
        run: |
          pulumi stack rm github-${{ github.run_id }} -y
```

Now also the app.pulumi.com overview looks like this when running multiple GitHub Actions workflows in parallel:

[image]